# MYSQLI/PHP How do I have to define my query/statement to output every message that was sent in a particular chatroom?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a page named chatroomChoice.php where I output all the chatrooms I saved in my PMA database, as ankers. If I click on it, I get redirected to chat.php through GET parameter and the name of the chatroom gets initiated as GET parameter like "index.php?page=chat&room=Nintendo". So I arrive at chat.php or better to say at "index.php?page=chat&room=Nintendo" where I do a require once of my database config file (4 constants saved into a link). Then i am defining a variable called $sql, where I add my query. I have three tables in my Database, tbluser, tblchatroom, tblsent. tblsent is an associative table that combines the foreign key of the chatroom, the foreign key of the user and the message the user sent in that particular chatroom (look screenshot) the other two tables just contain basic informations like the name of the chatroom or the name of a user. Now I would like to run a SELECT-query which should return every message that has been sent in that chatroom including the username of the person taht sent that message. My query currently looks like this --> SELECT fiUser, dtMessage FROM ((tblsent INNER JOIN tblchatroom ON fiChatroom = idChatroom WHERE fiChatroom = ?) INNER JOIN tbluser ON fiUser = idUser). Yes I use prepared statements, even if there is no input to secure.
After I set the $sql variable with that mysqli SELECT query, i do an mysqli_prepare of my database link variable (which contains the 4 constants to login to PMA database) and my query aka $sql, I bind a variable containing the name of the current chatroom gathered through the GET parameter, to  the $stmt variable which i used to initiate with the mysqli prepare. Then i am executing the $stmt, storing its result, and with a for loop

```
for ( $f = 0 ; $f < mysqli_num_rows ( $stmt ) ; $f++ ) {
    
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $stmt );        
    echo $row;          
}
```

the echo of `$row` is for checking, if there is something in it.
But the echo row does not contain anything even if I set example values in my database.

CODE OF CHAT.PHP HERE:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="create">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="label">
                <label for="chat">Text chat</label>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <input type="text" name="Data_Chat" id="chat" maxlength="255">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Chat senden" name="BUTTON_send" id="Chat">
        </div>
</form>

<?php
    
    if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    
        require_once "includes/php/config.php";
        
        $_SESSION["chatroom"] = $_GET["rooms"];
        $param_chatroom = $_SESSION["chatroom"];
        $param_user = $_SESSION["username"];
        
        $sql = "SELECT fiUser, dtMessage FROM ((tblsent INNER JOIN tblchatroom ON fiChatroom = idChatroom WHERE fiChatroom = ?) INNER JOIN tbluser ON fiUser = idUser)";
        
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
            
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_chatroom);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                
                // store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                for ( $f = 0 ; $f < mysqli_num_rows ( $stmt ) ; $f++ ) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $stmt );
                    
                    echo $row;
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.<br>";
                echo mysqli_errno($link) . " " . mysqli_error($link) . "<br>";
                
            }
            
            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            
        }
    
    } else {
        
        header("Location: index.php?page=login");
        
    }


?>
```

DATABASE LOOKS LIKE:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Erstellungszeit: 06. Jul 2021 um 22:08
-- Server-Version: 10.4.19-MariaDB
-- PHP-Version: 8.0.6

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Datenbank: `db_chat`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `tblchatroom`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblchatroom` (
  `idChatroom` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `dtName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `dtChatIcon` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `tblchatroom`
--

INSERT INTO `tblchatroom` (`idChatroom`, `dtName`, `dtChatIcon`) VALUES
(1, 'Mario', 'https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/100/000000/super-mario.png'),
(2, 'Luigi', 'https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/100/000000/super-mario.png'),
(3, 'Maki', 'https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/100/000000/super-mario.png'),
(4, 'lor', 'https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/100/000000/super-mario.png');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `tblsent`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblsent` (
  `fiChatroom` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `fiUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dtMessage` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `tblsent`
--

INSERT INTO `tblsent` (`fiChatroom`, `fiUser`, `dtMessage`) VALUES
(1, 19, 'Hello World');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `tbluser`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbluser` (
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dtName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `dtLastName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `dtUserName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `dtPasswordHash` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `tbluser`
--

INSERT INTO `tbluser` (`idUser`, `dtName`, `dtLastName`, `dtUserName`, `dtPasswordHash`) VALUES
(19, 'Nicolas', 'Scheer', 'Kreckelneckel', '$2y$10$FWSPlpOK..LUMtoRDxTkgeqTKdzh/8sROUWB5dmntHiHAieCDDSV2');

--
-- Indizes der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `tblchatroom`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblchatroom`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idChatroom`);

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `tblsent`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblsent`
  ADD KEY `Chatroom` (`fiChatroom`),
  ADD KEY `User` (`fiUser`);

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `tbluser`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbluser`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT für exportierte Tabellen
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT für Tabelle `tblchatroom`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblchatroom`
  MODIFY `idChatroom` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT für Tabelle `tbluser`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbluser`
  MODIFY `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=23;

--
-- Constraints der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Constraints der Tabelle `tblsent`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblsent`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Chatroom` FOREIGN KEY (`fiChatroom`) REFERENCES `tblchatroom` (`idChatroom`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `User` FOREIGN KEY (`fiUser`) REFERENCES `tbluser` (`idUser`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: `$row` is an array, you can't echo an array. Use `var_dump($row);`

Comment: It doesn't change anything, the array still is empty @Barmar

Comment: You have a syntax error in your query. You can't have a `WHERE` clause inside an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Try: `SELECT fiUser, dtMessage FROM tblsent 
INNER JOIN tblchatroom ON fiChatroom = idChatroom 
INNER JOIN tbluser ON fiUser = idUser
WHERE fiChatroom = 1`

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4537c/3